# Why is my Language Switcher Dropdown block NOT displayed in my site?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a multi-language site in Drupal 7. And I use the [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) module in it. I enabled all the settings required by this module, as described in the module's [readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/lang_dropdown/tree/README.txt). I have also assigned the block to new region. But still the Language Switcher Dropdown block is not displayed anywhere in my site.

What are the other settings I may have to review/configure? Or maybe there is a possible plugin which conflicts with this one that causes the block not to be displayed?

Comment: If there is no translation available for the page your on, the language switcher probably doesn't show... Are you sure there are translations available?

Answer (score 3):

make sure that:

1. add few languages to site here - admin/config/regional/language
2. enable one of Detection Methods here - admin/config/regional/language/configure
3. clear cache

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you also enabled the core modules "Locale" and "Content translation", as mentioned in the modules [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2451133) (so that's probably not the reason for the block being displayed). And I'm assuming that you have more then 1 language enabled (otherwise there is no other language to switch to, right?).

However, a *possible* reason for the block not being displayed, is because of what is mentioned in the issue "[Does not work without URL-detection](https://www.drupal.org/node/1869260)" ... More specifically in [Comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1869260#comment-8221267) of that issue it says:

> If not url detection, nor session detection or both are enabled then the switcher will not be shown by design as on those cases the selection of the language is done by other means: user profile, language sended by browser, **so there is no reason to show a switcher**.

Curious to hear if "this" is what explains your issue ... If this is not the reason in your case, then consider editing your question a bit to eliminate this as possible reasons.